# Changing wordpress language through API

Tags: wordpress

I need to deploy sixteen wordpress instances at once and nope, wordpress network is not an option.

I'm trying to customize each instance language programmatically after its deploy.
I managed to customize anything else I need.

Neither of these solutions seem to work:

1. set $locale="es_ES" in wp-config.php
2. update_option("WPLANG", "es_ES") //return false
3. update_blog_option(1, "WPLANG", "es_ES") //return false
4. update_site_option("WPLANG", "es_ES") //just for network, but at least returns true but setting wplang option to null

Language keeps being the default english. Any solution?

EDIT:

Kevin was actually right.
You need to:

1) Download the correct language pack (.mo files) from http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/

2) update wp_options set option_value = "de_DE" where option_name = "wplang";

I thought I need not to download anything since you can set any language in the admin panel, but digging in the code I found out that wordpress is download files under the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language ?

From reading it, you need to upload .mo files in the proper directory beforehand. From there, depends on the version of WordPress, either wp-config or database change.

Comment: Yes: wordpress is already available in this language, I can manually change the admin language by the settings page. Wp-config updating is deprecated, I'm on the last worpdress version.

Comment: Updating WPLANG seems to be the proper way. What if you edit the wp_options manually?

    UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'es_ES' WHERE option_name = 'WPLANG';

Comment: With the following doesn't work either: insert into wp_options set option_name = "WPLANG", option_value = "es_ES";

Comment: and I have to say that there is no default setting named WPLANG

Comment: I guess the process to figure this out would be reverse engineering what doing it manually from the admin does. I did a quick search through the WordPress repo (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=WPLANG) and the way it seems to do it is update_option( 'WPLANG', $language ); And if you do update manually you're seeing WPLANG and value of 'es_ES'? If that's the case I'm stumped.

Comment: no, update_option( 'WPLANG', "es_ES" ); return false without setting the option. I guess I'll have to dig deeper into wp sources to figure this out, and I'll bet I'll curl the instance to simulate the form in settings page..